# Como armazenar estado de um checkbox

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para fazer uma lista de chamada escolar , eu criei o `Listview` e populei ele com dados de uma base de dados `Mysql`, utilizando `Json`. O problema é o seguinte, preciso armazenar o estado dos `checkbox` selecionados. Por exemplo`:

O usuário marcou o `checkbox` de falta para o Aluno 1 e o `checkbox` de presença para o aluno 2 , como armazenar o estado dos `check-box` para depois inseri-los em uma tabela de frequência no MySQL via JSON e PHP.

Comment: Poste o código do `form` ou do `checkbox`.

Comment: Todos os elementos da tela são objetos acessíveis pelo JavaScript, dessa forma o estado está sempre lá enquanto a tela não recarregar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dois checkbox um para falta e outro para presença, nessa caso parece melhor um `radio button` pois somente uma opção pode ser marcada. os valores `m1, m2 ...` entenda como a matricula ou código do aluno quem do banco. O deve ser feito é torna esse radio um array, adicionando colchetes no name e deixar quer o indice seja a matricula.

```
<?php
$alunos = array('m1' => 'joão', 'm2' => 'maria', 'm3' => 'juca', 'm4' => 'paula', 'm5' => 'fulano');
?>

<form action="gravar_falta.php" method="post">
    <?php foreach ($alunos as $matricula => $nome){ ?>
    <?php echo $nome; ?>
    presente
    <input type="radio" name="frequencia[<?php echo $matricula; ?>]" value="presente">
    falta
    <input type="radio" name="frequencia[<?php echo $matricula; ?>]" value="falta"><br>

    <?php } ?>  
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Esses radios vão ser enviados ao php com um array nessa estrutura:

```
Array
(
    [frequencia] => Array
        (
            [m1] => presente
            [m2] => falta
            [m3] => falta
            [m4] => presente
            [m5] => falta
        )

)
```

Por último basta basta fazer um foreach para inserir no banco :

```
$aula = 'português';
$frequencias = $_POST['frequencia'];

foreach ($frequencias as $aluno => $frequencia){
    insertFequencia($aula, $aluno, $frequencia);    
}
```

Comment: Com relação ao envio e armazenamento vc me ajudou muito, porem estou com dificuldades na codificação em Java.
Como que eu posso referenciar um Radio Button a um aluno(Registro do bd) e depois armazena-lo em um array ?

Comment: CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chkAlunos);
                chk.setTag(Alunos);
                chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) v;
    String aluno = (String) chk.getTag();
    if (chk.isChecked()) ????

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução que eu costumo fazer para lidar com isso é ter um campo hidden com o código do usuário e mesmo name, e nos checkboxes concateno o name deles com o código do campo hidden, dessa forma no lado do servidor eu sei quantos códigos eu posso esperar e verifico se o valor da checkbox veio (true) ou não (false)

Vou colocar um exemplo de como seria em ASP:

HTML:

```
<tr>
     <td>
          <input type="hidden" name="hddCodigo" value="1"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="chkFalta1" value="1"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="chkPresenca1" value="1"/>
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>
          <input type="hidden" name="hddCodigo" value="2"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="chkFalta2" value="1"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="chkPresenca2" value="1"/>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Server-Side / ASP

```
For Each iCodAluno In Request.Form("hddCodigo")
    'Se o check estiver marcado, o tamanho (Len) do valor será maior que 0 e a variável receberá True.
    bFalta = Len(Request("chkFalta" & iCodAluno)) > 0 
    bPresenca = Len(Request("chkPresenca" & iCodAluno)) > 0

    'Logica para atualizar os dados por aluno....
Next
```

Comment: Rogerio , 
Obrigado pela atenção
Então , vc tem um código de exemplo desta solução ?
Não sei se eu deixei claro , mas tipo eu preciso armazenar o estado dos checkboxes e depois inseri-los no banco de dados para posteriormente consultar as faltas e presenças dos alunos.

Comment: @Danilo, atualizei a resposta com uma solução em ASP que seria bem possivel fazer em PHP ou JSP, é só adaptar !